# How to replace $(document).ready() with $(document).on()

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

I'm pretty new to JQuery. I'm using [this](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started) JQuery function to show a tooltip on elements.

I edited the code this way, according to my needs (with the help of this community):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('.toolTipField').each(function() {
     $(this).tooltipster({
         content: $('<span>' + $(this).attr("data-tooltipText") + '</span>')
     });
   });
});
```

I need to show tooltip also on elements added to the DOM with this JQuery function:

```
$("#element").clone().appendTo("#target")
```

Now the tooltip doesn't work on the elements added to the DOM with JQuery. Looking into internet I found out that I have to use the method `on()` instead of `ready()`, but I'm don't know how to edit correctly my code.

Thank everybody.

Comment: So call the tooltip code after you append the elements... `on` is not going to work for you in this situation.

Comment: I see. Any solution?

Comment: Call the tooltipster code on the cloned element. If you do not want to have repeated code, make a method and call it.

Comment: `var myClone = $('el').clone(); myClone.appendTo('target'); myClone.tooltipster({....});`

Comment: also, you don't need anything to do with on() in this case

Comment: You should try @epascarello's answer, clean and easy to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event delegation will not solve your problem. It does not dyncamically detect when elements are added to the document. You need to manually call the code to add your tooltip. Best thing to do is to factor out the code so it is reusable and than call the method on ready and when you clone the element.

```
function addToolTips (elems) {
   elems.each(function() {
     $(this).tooltipster({
         content: $('<span>' + $(this).attr("data-tooltipText") + '</span>')
     });
   });
}


$(document).ready(function() {  
   addToolTips($('.toolTipField'))
});
```

and when you clone the element

```
var clonedElem = $("#element").clone().appendTo("#target");
addToolTips(clonedElem);
```

Comment: Super perfect solution!! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var myClone = $('el').clone(); 
myClone.appendTo('target'); 
myClone.tooltipster({....});
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery gives you the elements existing in that moment, not the ones you add later on. If you add them, you will have to add the tooltip also